# iPhone two cameras at the same time

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I was googling for can I make an app that runs the two cameras at the same time

fornt and back 
and I found nothing so I am asking here ?

Any Info are appreciated , tutorial or articles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately this is impossible. Only one video capture device can be configured at the same time. The strict graph of AVCaptureSession which can be configured is described in AV Foundation Programming Guide. Media capture https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/04_MediaCapture.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188-CH5-SW2